# Android app - Show another activity in small window when pressing the button

Tags: android, android-activity, touch

I'm new developer in android ...and programming with intellij .

How i can show another activty when i pressing the button and close it when i release my finger of button ?
Similar to samsung keyboard that when we pressing the key show the larger version of that above it ?

I'm really need to know it .. thanks for your helps .

Answer (score 0):

Though this is not a proper answer of your question but this may help you because it helped me.

- You can use a popup window or something like this instead of activity.
  [Android PopupWindow with Tooltip Arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031488/android-popupwindow-with-tooltip-arrow)
- If you do then follow this.
  ["Press and hold" button on Android needs to change states (custom XML selector) using onTouchListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590169/android-press-and-hold-button-needs-to-change-states-custom-xml-selector-u)

Thanks

Comment: Although this is not answer , but thanks for your suggestions . ♧